# Toggling feature of stopwatch using configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jakarta-ee, stopwatch

Is there any way I can control stopwatch of Spring util package using configuration in application.yml or application.properties so that I can toggle(switch ON/OFF) the feature if and when required basis ?

P.S. I am aware that the documentation states that it is not designed to be thread-safe and is also not meant to be used in production.

Answer (score 0):

You can always manage an object using spring and also make it conditional so as that object needs to be made or not.

Do something like:

```
    public class StopWatchOnOffCondition implements Condition {

    @Override
    public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata arg1) {

        return !"false".equalsIgnoreCase(context.getEnvironment().getProperty("stopwatch.enabled"));
}
```

And when you create the bean for StopWatch you can do something like:

```
    @Conditional(value = { StopWatchOnOffCondition.class })
    @Service
    public class StopWatchService { ...
}
```

The property: stopwatch.enabled would reside in your applicaton.properties file.

Read more about `@Conditional` [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html)

Comment: how and where you call the matches() method ?

Comment: when you use the @Conditional annotation spring framework calls the matches() method

Comment: problem with this method is I have both spring and plain java modules using stopwatch. In plain java, bean creation using @Conditional doesn't hols good.

Comment: You mean to say that there are some objects managed by spring and some you are managing yourselves using the new keyword? Which is not an ideal setup to work with (let spring manage all the dependencies always). You can do one thing here that autowire the boolean flag stopwatch.enabled and create a util method (static) which can see if this flag is off then donot use the functionality (in plain java code) otherwise use it.

Comment: Any luck, did you try this?

Comment: It does not suit my requirement. Because, I am conditionally creating a bean and using @Autowired to use that bean everywhere to use the methods of that bean. So, in the way you suggested, it will throw null pointer when the condition is false.